# Titanium: Grouped tableview background on iPad

Tags: ipad, titanium, appcelerator, grouped-table

Is there a way to work around the grouped tableview background problem on the iPad?

I found some questions with the answer to check the following link:
 [Ticket](https://appcelerator.lighthouseapp.com/projects/32238-titanium-mobile/tickets/1738-grouped-table-does-not-honor-background-color-of-the-table-view#ticket-1738-5)

The problem is that this link doesn't work for me. It says it's not a public project. So can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to change the default background of group tableview?

Comment: Well on the iPhone, when you have the grouped tableview style, the background is the striped one. However when you run the app on the iPad it's just plain white. I want it to be just like the iPhone background.

Comment: Appcelerator has moved to JIRA for bug tracking so the ticket is now in that repository http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/04/platform-engineering-transitioning-to-jira-for-issue-tracking.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug, which they still haven't changed so it seems.

So if anyone reads this post and has the same problem, you could create a jira ticket.

Tjeu

Answer (score 1):

On the iPad, the grouped table view color is the same as clear color. You need to set your own (pattern) color or use a background view. This is NOT a jira problem, it's by design in iOS.